# If condition in MySQL Stored Procedure not evaluating properly

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have written the below mentioned procedure in MySQL.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `IsUploaderLoggedIn`(
IN `inMobile` CHAR(10),
IN `inSessionID` varchar(34)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE isLoggedIn TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE uploaderType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '';
CALL GetUploaderType(inMobile, @x);
SELECT @x INTO uploaderType;
IF uploaderType = "surveyor" THEN
    SELECT Count(*) INTO isLoggedIn FROM surveyors WHERE Mobile = inMobile AND SessionID = inSessionID;
    SELECT "surveyor";
ELSE
    SELECT Count(*) INTO isLoggedIn FROM uploaders WHERE Mobile = inMobile AND SessionID = inSessionID;
    SELECT "uploader";
END IF;
SELECT isLoggedIn;
END;
```

On executing the procedure in **Navicat**, for a given value of `inMobile` and `inSessionID`, the values returned are:

Result 1: usertype | surveyor

Result 1(2): uploader | uploader

Result 1(3): 0 or 1 as the case may be

Where as, the value of Result 1(2)s should have been **surveyor | surveyor**.

Below is definition of stored procedure `GetUploaderType`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUploaderType`(
IN `inMobile` CHAR(10),
OUT `Usertype` VARCHAR(8)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE usertype VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE userExists TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
/*SET officeExists = 0;*/
/* Check if mobile number belongs to a surveyor */
SELECT Count(*) INTO userExists FROM surveyors WHERE Mobile = inMobile;
IF userExists = 1 THEN
    SET usertype = 'surveyor';
ELSE
    /* If user is not surveyor, check for it in uploaders */
    SELECT Count(*) INTO userExists FROM uploaders WHERE Mobile = inMobile;
    IF userExists = 1 THEN
        SET usertype = 'uploader';
    END IF;
END IF;
SELECT usertype;
```

END

What is wrong with my script please?

Comment: What do you get if you run CALL GetUploaderType(inMobile, @x); with the values you're passing in.

Comment: The value of variable `uploaderType` in procedure `IsUploaderLoggedIn()`.

Comment: Are the tables' `Mobile` fields unique? If not, you'd skip "surveyor" any time there was more than one; you could try `userExists <> 0` instead to avoid that.

Comment: The value of field `Mobile` are Unique and Not Null. By the way, I have noticed that the procedure `GetUploaderType()` is not returning value in OUT parameter `Usertype`, thus causing the problem in procedure `IsUploaderLoggedIn`. Hence the procedure `GetUploaderType()` is to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GetUploaderType`, you redeclared the variable `Usertype`, thus hiding the (different) `out`-variable of the same name, see [scope](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> The scope of a local variable is the BEGIN ... END block within which it is declared. The variable can be referred to in blocks nested within the declaring block, except those blocks that declare a variable with the same name.